# How to prevent caching on brunch watch -s

Tags: brunch

I'm building an ember application and have found that I constantly need to restart the `brunch watch -s` command, to have my application updated. While brunch recompiles on every change, the changes only pull through if I restart the command.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way around this problem?

Note: Browser caching is turned off

**Update**: I figured out how to debug brunch ;) What I found is the following:

```
 brunch:common Writing file 'public/javascripts/app.js' +14s
29 May 20:47:46 - info: compiled in 73ms
 brunch:watch File 'app/templates/contact.hbs' received event 'change' +3s
 brunch:file-list Compiled file 'app/templates/contact.hbs' +3s
 brunch:generated-file Joining files 'app/app.js, app/controllers/contact.js, app/initialize.js, app/models/category.js, app/models/marker.js, app/models/stock.js, app/routes/application.js, app/routes/category/index.js, app/routes/contact.js, app/templates/about.hbs, app/templates/application.hbs, app/templates/blog.hbs, app/templates/categories.hbs, app/templates/category.hbs, app/templates/category/index.hbs, app/templates/contact.hbs, app/templates/contactEntry.hbs, app/templates/index.hbs, app/templates/new.hbs, app/templates/specials.hbs, app/views/contact.js, app/views/contactEntry.js' to 'public/javascripts/app.js' +3s
 brunch:common Writing file 'public/javascripts/app.js' +3s
29 May 20:47:50 - info: compiled in 73ms
 brunch:watch File 'app/templates/contact.hbs' received event 'unlink' +6s
29 May 20:47:57 - info: compiled in 67ms
 brunch:watch File 'app/templates/contact.hbs' received event 'add' +99ms
 brunch:source-file Initializing fs_utils.SourceFile: {"path":"app/templates/contact.hbs","isHelper":false,"isVendor":false} +10s
 brunch:file-list Compiled file 'app/templates/contact.hbs' +6s
 brunch:generated-file Joining files 'app/app.js, app/controllers/contact.js, app/initialize.js, app/models/category.js, app/models/marker.js, app/models/stock.js, app/routes/application.js, app/routes/category/index.js, app/routes/contact.js, app/templates/about.hbs, app/templates/application.hbs, app/templates/blog.hbs, app/templates/categories.hbs, app/templates/category.hbs, app/templates/category/index.hbs, app/templates/contact.hbs, app/templates/contactEntry.hbs, app/templates/index.hbs, app/templates/new.hbs, app/templates/specials.hbs, app/views/contact.js, app/views/contactEntry.js' to 'public/javascripts/app.js' +6s
 brunch:common Writing file 'public/javascripts/app.js' +6s
```

Notice how sometimes it receives the unlink event, but then doesn't rebuild the files. I tested this by making small changes to only the contact.hbs file. Why is it that the server sometimes rebuilds and sometimes not?

Comment: sounds like a bug. do you see any caching headers in brunch-served-server files?

Comment: I've checked the server headers, and there are plenty of no-cache headers. I have another brunch project setup and it works somewhat better. Could there be a config problem somewhere?

Comment: highly doubt it, maybe you’re using custom server though (config.server.path)

Comment: It does the same thing for me. First `brunch watch` will compile in ~5000ms or so, but every subsequent one in a meagre 50-100ms or so, and it doesn't pick up the change. So essentially I may as well just run `brunch compile` after every save! (Standard installation on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my [discussion with Paul Miller](http://ost.io/@brunch/brunch/topics/90), this was fixed in 1.7.0 pre and will be released soon